# Reference for this polyhedral lemma

Tags: convex-polytopes, fans, co.combinatorics

Recall the definition of a fan: Let $U$ be a finite dimensional real vector space. Then a fan is a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of cones in $U$ such that

(1) If $\sigma \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$, then $\tau \in \mathcal{F}$.

(2) If $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2 \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\sigma_1 \cap \sigma_2$ is a face of both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

The following is widely known: Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of cones in $U$ obeying (2). Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of all faces of cones in $\mathcal{S}$ (so $\mathcal{F}$ obeys (1)). Then $\mathcal{F}$ obeys (2).

Is there a standard person and reference to whom this observation is attributed?

Comment: Added a bounty as an excuse for bumping this to the front page. I'm finishing up a paper which uses this fact, and I'd like to get my references right.

Comment: You might look in _Combinatorial convexity and algebraic geometry_
by Günter Ewald, to which Ziegler's _Lectures on Polytopes_ refers in his discussion of fans.  Just a guess; I don't have Ewald's book.

Comment: Grünbaum's book (Convex Polytopes, 2nd ed) has some discussion in 3.2: a fan is a special case of a polyhedral complex, for which notion he refers to the books of Alexandroff-Hopf and Lefschetz.  

I see Ewald has a similar discussion.  Neither explicitly states what you want, it seems.  They both observe that the boundary complex of a polyhedron (say, cone) is a polyhedral complex (fan).  Grünbaum's exercise 7 makes you prove almost what you want.  

So you might try Alexandroff's Combinatorial Topology for an explicit reference, since it's at least in translation.